# Break ArrayList and display in Struts 1

Tags: java, jsp, controller, struts, struts-action

I'm stuck with a problem of displaying an `ArrayList` that carries 2750 rows. The struts code to display row is :

```
<c:forEach items="${customerlist}" var="beneficiaryListval"varStatus="ForIndex" >
<tr id="<c:out value="${beneficiaryListval.customerId}" />">
  <td><c:out value="${beneficiaryListval.fullName}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${beneficiaryListval.mobileNo}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${beneficiaryListval.passportNo}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${beneficiaryListval.beneficiaryCount}" /></td>
</tr>
<%rowID++;%>
</c:forEach>
```

The action method for this is :

```
public ActionForward load(ActionMapping actionMapping,ActionForm     actionForm,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
try {
mtmrsLogger.entering("BeneficiaryAction", "load");
BeneficiaryForm beneficiaryForm = (BeneficiaryForm) actionForm;
ArrayList customerlist = customerManager.getCustomerForBeneficiaryWithCount();
httpServletRequest.setAttribute("customerlist", customerlist);
beneficiaryForm.setPageStatus("CustomerGrid");
return actionMapping.findForward(Constants.getInstance().SUCCESS);
}
```

Now i need to either break the `ArrayList customerlist` and send to the JSP in chunks of fifty and display OR display them in the JSP so that it is not very slow while rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing 2750 records in a **List** is not a suggested way. Please consider its implication when you reading it from DB/storage and also when you passing it around on your web/app server. Also you might not need all of them in one go.

Please consider fetching and displaying data in chunks like 100 at one time. You can always make a new call to server to get next set of records by passing index.

Also you will have to use Ajax if you are not using still; this way you can keep appending the remaining data to the page without refreshing.

Comment: I've started using jqGrid and jqueryUI theme to fulfill the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use pagination mechanism so that You will load 50 or 100 records at a given time. have a look on this [extremetable](http://code.google.com/p/extremetable/)

Answer (score 0):

The [Struts `<logic:iterate>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-logic.html#iterate) tag has `offset` and `length` attributes which can be used to display sections of a collection. The below would display the first 50 elements in the `ArrayList`.

```
<logic:iterate name="customerlist" id="customer" indexId="customerNum" offset="0" length="50">
    <tr id="${customer.customerId}">
        <td>${customer.fullName}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: In this case do you have to load all 2750 records in to memory ?

Comment: @guess_me yes, you will have the db send you 2750 records which you convert to 2750 objects only to use 50 of them.

Comment: But this would display only 50 rows, i need to show ALL the data but rendered 50 at  a time.

Comment: @Survivor-2012 What does that even mean? Are you trying to implement paging?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't break the list `customerlist`  to "send to the jsp in chunks". Instead you can break the method that will return a given number of records, i.e. `customerManager.getCustomerForBeneficiaryWithCount(perPage);` or use JSP logic tags to limit rendering rows using two parameters `firstRow` and `perPage`.